# use business days pandas .Timedelta function

Tags: pandas, timedelta

is there any way to get the pandas .Timedelta function to accept a business day argument instead of calendar days? Also the BDay function is not compatible with my code

```
# works
pd.Timedelta('1d') 

# doesn't work
pd.Timedelta('1b') or ('1B')
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, why doesn't using BDay work?  where df.Date is dtype: datetime64[ns] both df.Date + BDay(4) works and df.Date + pd.Timedelta('1d') work.  Where Bday respects weekends, pd.Timedelta just increments calendar days.

Comment: I get TypeError: Cannot compare type 'Timestamp' with type 'date'

Comment: something is odd about the format of the df.Date I am using which I cannot change. when I run dtype on it I get: TypeError: data type not understood

Comment: Are the results of df.info()?  can you convert to pandas Timestamp?  df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.Date)

Comment: <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 475 entries, 0 to 474
Data columns (total 2 columns):
Future's Ticker    475 non-null object
Last Trade Date    475 non-null object
dtypes: object(2)
memory usage: 7.5+ KB

Comment: when I try to convert to_datetime I get: AttributeError: 'Name' object has no attribute 'lower'